# Different behavior depending on whether the DAG is manually triggered or not

Tags: airflow

I know Airflow distinguishes between manual and scheduled triggers of a DAG - the pattern of their ID is different, and also the UI in Tree View shows an outlined circle for one but not the other.

I have a DAG that uses a Python callable as `on_failure_callback` to emit failure alert. I now want to modify this DAG so that it will emit one type of alert when a *manually triggered* run fails, while emitting a different alert when the run was triggered by the scheduler.

I can do this by simply parsing the string in `{{ execution_date }}`. However, that seems hacky. Is there a flag that I can check instead?

Comment: I've been using SO for >10 years and I think this is the first time I flagged my own question, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very related to this question:
[Can I programmatically determine if an Airflow DAG was scheduled or manually triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077575/can-i-programmatically-determine-if-an-airflow-dag-was-scheduled-or-manually-tri)

Looks like you can look up the run_id and parse that instead which might be slightly better.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! Mine is indeed a dupe of that question.